# Updating a record on a subform

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, subform

I have a main form and a subform in Access.  The main form is to provide information regarding to a site that my company will be working from.  The subform shows all of the individuals that are available on the days in question, so that they can be provisionally booked.  These forms are not linked in anyway as, at this stage, there is nothing to link them on.

On my subform (which is a continuous form), I have a button linked to an update query.  I think I need some sort of SetFocus or criteria to show that it is only for that one record.

```sql
UPDATE Dates SET Dates.[Booked?] = True, Dates.[Site ID] = [Forms]![Frm5 - EditMS]![ID];
```

When I click the button next to each record for the individual that I want to book, it is updating all the records and not just the one that I want.  I have tried to add in criteria as in Individual in table=form field individual (brief overview, obviously) but then it asks me for a parameter so it is not working as I planned.
I did try searching the forums but can't seem to find the right words in a search to find the answer!  I'm sure it is out there somewhere but I have no idea where to find it!

Thank you in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot smarter to update using the subform where the records are present:

```
Private Sub BookButton_Click()

    If Me.[Booked?].Value = False Then
        Me.[Booked?].Value = True
        ' Save the record.
        Me.Dirty = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I have added this in and changed the sub the correct control but, when I click the button now, I get a run-time error 2448 - You cannot assign a value to this object.

Comment: I also tried changing the sub to a function but that doesn't work either :(

Comment: Thank you for your help.  How do I change it from being read only?  Do I need to reference the table that I need to update instead?

Comment: Just had a look at my query behind the form and there was a join so the recordset was not updateable.  I removed the join and made sure that I was able to adjust the data in the form and I can.  However, when I click the button now, nothing happens.  it looks as though it is running but nothing is updating in the table.  Any ideas please?

Comment: Not without your query.